# Intro To x86 Assembly With Windows

Tags: windows, assembly, resources

There's a chapter in Robbins' *[Debugging Microsoft Windows Applications](http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/80061562&referer=brief_results)* where he discusses the assembly code created for Windows apps.  This is a community wiki question--please post links to other books, websites, blogs, articles etc. which discuss the x86 assembly code generated by Windows.  I'm looking for a little more in-depth discussion of assembly and Windows.

If this was asked and answered somewhere else, please post a link and I'll close this question.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure *exactly* what you're seeking here, but I'd like to point out that since assembly language is specific to a processor architecture, as opposed to a particular OS, one of the best places to seek information about x86 assembly language is to go to the manufacturer -- Intel -- and read their [processor manuals](http://www.intel.com/products/processor/manuals/). Volume 2 is of particular interest.

Comment: Actually after having worked with some people who know assembly and Windows programming, I think I would have been better off to ask for a book discussing assembly in relation to Windows compilers.